# Applying animation outside of the ngApp

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My goal is to create a directive that can be applied to a given element, so that when the element is clicked, a modal is created.  I would like to have the modal created and appended to the body node, which is outside of my ng-app element.  Due to requirements of more than one app on a page, I can't put ng-app on the `<html>` or `<body>` tags.  Yet for proper z positioning, I would to place the modal element as high up in the body as I can.

My directive looks like this:

```js
var module = angular.module('Test', ['ngAnimate']);
module.directive('modal', function($compile, $animate) {
    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            var modal = $compile('<div class="modal"></div>')(scope);
            scope.$apply(function () {
                $animate.enter(modal, angular.element(document.body));
            });
        });

    }

    return {
        link: link,
        scope: {}
    };

});
```

When I use `$animate.enter` to append the `modal` to the body, it is appended but the animation does not run.  My HTML looks like this:

```html
  <body>
    <div ng-app="Test">
      <button modal>Open Modal</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

If I move the `ng-app` from the `div` to the `body`, then the animation works.  But I can't do this because I need to have the option of placing more than one `ng-app` on a given page.

Is it possible?

Working (or not-working) example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vUi2PmLjea36nrJ9i3R2?p=preview

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with angular not "watching" that part of the DOM and therefore not processing any extra directives that animate is depending on.  I'm thinking maybe you just make a dummy module that you apply at the top level and see if that works.

Comment: @drukepple: Anything wrong with my answer ? Was it too long or something ?

Comment: Sorry, @ExpertSystem, got distracted by other things and wasn't paying attention to activity on Stack Overflow.  Your answer was very helpful and educational; personally, I love the long answers that explain these kinds of details. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No you can't.
(At least Angular seems not to be designed to allow it).

---

The somewhat longer answer is: No, you can't. Here is why:

The reason is how `$animate` is currently implemented:

In your case, it adds the elements= to the DOM (to `document.body` in particular) and then checks to see if it should proceed with the animation specific stuff (or if animations are "disabled").
According to the source code, the function that checks if animations are "disabled" is:

```
function animationsDisabled(element, parentElement) {
  if (rootAnimateState.disabled) return true;

  if(isMatchingElement(element, $rootElement)) {
    return rootAnimateState.disabled || rootAnimateState.running;
  }

  do {
    //the element did not reach the root element which means that it
    //is not apart of the DOM. Therefore there is no reason to do
    //any animations on it
    if(parentElement.length === 0) break;

    var isRoot = isMatchingElement(parentElement, $rootElement);
    var state = isRoot ? rootAnimateState : parentElement.data(NG_ANIMATE_STATE);
    var result = state && (!!state.disabled || state.running || state.totalActive > 0);
    if(isRoot || result) {
      return result;
    }

    if(isRoot) return true;
  }
  while(parentElement = parentElement.parent());

  return true;
}
```

As you can see, since your modal is not a child (but a sibling) of the $rootElement, `isRoot` will always be false and the `do-while` loop will run until there is no parent-element. At that point `if(parentElement.length === 0) break;` will break the loop and the function will return `true`, thus cancelling the animation.

---

The longest answer is: Depends (on how badly you need it).

The available options (I can think of) are:

1. Accept your fate and find some other way (besides `$animate`) to perform your animations.
2. Create your own fork of angular-animate and change one line of code, so that animations are not cancelled even if the target-element is not a child of the $rootElement.
3. If you like to live dangerously: What if we "temporarily swapped the $rootElement" ?
   I tried various approaches (which outside of the scope of this answer) and the only one I could make work(?), was swapping the HTML element associated with the jqLite object (i.e. `$rootElement[0]`).

I wrapped the functionality in a service (along with some convenience features, e.g. restoring the original element after a set period of time):

```
module.factory('myRootElement', function ($rootElement, $timeout) {
    /* Save the original element for reference */
    var original = $rootElement[0];

    /* Fake the $rootElement for the specified 
     * period of time (in milliseconds) */
    function fakeForMillis(millis) {
        $rootElement[0] = document.body;
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootElement[0] = original;
        }, millis || 0);
    }

    /* Return the Service object */
    return {
        fakeForMillis: fakeForMillis
    };
});
```

Finally, you only need to temporarily swap the `$rootElement` fo the animation to take place. (Unfortunately, you have to specify the time required for the animation, but I bet there are better ways to find it out programmatically - again outside the scope of this answer.)

```
myRootElement.fakeForMillis(1000);
$animate.enter(modal, angular.element(document.body));
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hESYhlXg7FQ48wmYlQQ?p=preview)**.

<sub>I have no idea what I am talking about and I have by no means investigated the consequences of this approach, so use at your own risk and don't be surprised if strange things come your way.</sub>